# Intel DH61WW Motherboard BIOS Update Issue

Tags: motherboard, bios, intel-core-i5

Recently i planned to upgrade my old PC which has Intel DH61 WW Motherboard, it had BIOS version 42 earlier and after i tried to update it to current update version 120 the update was failing. After searching through internet understood that it needs to be updated to version 48, then to version 99 and after that update to 120 was possible. I followed the process and got it updated till version 99 without any issues. After version 99 upgrade there is no issue with boot, the system is running widows 10 pretty good.

But the main issue is now it has stopped detecting the keyboard on Boot Menu screen (Earlier to 99 this issue wasn't there i was able to press F2 and it used to take me to BIOS Setup, i am using same keyboard which worked with earlier versions it's a USB keyboard), because of this i can't get into BIOS Menu(F2), BIOS Flash Update Menu(F7) or Boot Menu(F10).

System Config :

1. Intel i5-3570K.
2. Intel DH61WW.
3. 8GB Ram.
4. 2TB HDD.
5. Nvidia 1660Ti(This is what caused me to upgrade my BIOS in the first 
     place, as graphic card was casusing boot issues).
6. Corsair 550W VS550.

What can be done to resolve this, i tried intel site to find any chipset drivers etc. i cant find any supported drivers other than BIOS for this board. Using their "Auto Detect Driver" Software also did not help. I tried after installing Drivers for keyboard from the manufacturer site, that didn't work.

Now i am trying to Update the motherboard BIOS, thinking it may resolve this error. By pressing random keys on Keyboard on boot-screen it is taking me to BIOS Flash update menu, i tried updating to Version 120 with .BIO File its throwing below ERROR, same error comes when i try to do it with .exe file for bios update. What can be the issue here.[ERROR SCREEN Shown when BIOS Update is performed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ujpr.jpg)

Any help on this is appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: I despise motherboard manufacturers that pull drivers for older products, they suck. See if this utility finds any intel drivers for your system......https://downloadcenter.intel.com/

Comment: you can flash BIOS 120 update with that method. you must use BIOS recovery for that MB:

see this : https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-Desktop-Boards/DH61WW-BIOS-Update-and-Procedure-from-0020-up-to-0120/m-p/1295601/highlight/true#M56138